# Is it possible to use RelayJS and GraphQL without the ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way of using RelayJS and GraphQL without ReactJS. Im quite fond of how those three works in data management and at the same time, im looking forward on using the jeasyUI for the design of my web application. But the problem is jeasyUI doesnt really work well together with reactJS.

Im a newbie on this matter so please, please please, if you guys know any way on how to work on it. Enlighten me please. Any response regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use Relay without React, but it's possible to use GraphQL without Relay.

Relay is just one of several GraphQL clients, there are others like [Apollo client](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client) ( a client that supports React, Angular, React Native and any other frontend) and [Lokka](https://github.com/kadirahq/lokka) (a very simple client, without cache).

Answer (score 2):

At present facebook only support relay to be used with react or react native + GraphQL. But they are working on it to make it framework agnostic. You can try Apollo Client which is the best alternative for Relay out there and also has lots of cool features, if you want to choose different tech stack other than facebook's.